# VBA find, how to capture when there is nothing to find

Tags: vba, function, excel, find

I just wrote a seven page macro with two UserForms that is a thing of beauty.
There are two data bases and the one on the left is longer than the one on the right.

I use a variable DDataa1 and the VBA function:

```
Sub SSearchh()
... code ...
Cells.Find(What:=DDataa1, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
... code ...
End Sub
```

It works perfectly EXCEPT when there is no DDataa1 to find.  (That is, there is no variable in the right hand list that is being searched for in the left hand list.)

In that case the Macro just stops.  I want to capture this "data not found" event and write more code specific to this failure but this function does not seem to generate a True/False condition.

Specific assistance would be appreciated

Comment: So, you are activating whatever cell you found. But if nothing is found, Excel doesn't know what to Activate. Hence the error. Set it to range and check if the range is not nothing. `Not rngFound Is Nothing`

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
Dim FindRange As Range
Set FindRange = Cells.Find(What:=DDataa1, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If FindRange Is Nothing Then
    ' do error handling here
Else
    FindRange.Activate
End If
```